# ActiveQt: Activate an already open word document

Tags: c++, qt, ms-word, activeqt, qaxobject

I am trying to write to an open word document using activeQt. I am trying to activate my word document, but i cant get it to work.

I can do this in VBA very easily:

```
Documents("my.doc").Activate
```

but not in Qt, this is what i have tried:

```
wordApplication = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
doc = wordApplication->querySubObject("Documents()","my.doc");
doc->dynamicCall("Activate()");
```

Documents() is supposed to contain all the open word documents, but for me it is empty for some reason.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a parameter type in the function name (`querySubObject("Documents(QString)", "my.doc")`) ?

Comment: I have tried this but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem, by using the setControl function with the UUID for word I was able to access a word document that was already opened.

> ```
>  QAxObject* wordApplication;
>  QAxObject* doc;
>  wordApplication = new QAxObject(this);
>  wordApplication->setControl(("{000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}&"));
>  doc = wordApplication->querySubObject("Documents()","my.doc");
> ```